# AWS: EC2 micro, not enough for a .NET MVC 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

I used elastic beanstalk to manage/deploy my .NET MVC 3 application on an EC2 micro instance (has 613 MB memory). It's mainly a static site for now as it is in Beta with registration (including email confirmation) and some error logging (ELMAH).

It was doing fine until recently, I keep getting notifications of CPU Utilization greater than 95.00%.

Is the micro instance with 613MB memory not enough to run an MVC application for Production use?

Added info: Windows Server 2008 R2, running IIS7.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried running Jetbrains teamcity (which uses Tomcat I think) and was on a linux box using an ec2 micro instance and there wasn't enough memory available to support what it needed.

I did try running a server 2008/2012 box on a micro instance as well and it was pointless took minutes to open anything.

I think you're going to find that running windows on one of those boxes isn't really a viable option unless you start disabling services like crazy and get really creative with you're tweaking.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the response!

Comment: What OS are you running on it?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2, running IIS7.5

Answer (score 1):

A micro instance is clearly not enough for Production.

The micro instances have a low I/O limit, and once this limit is reached (for the month I think), all later operations are throttled.

So, I advise you to use at least a small instance for production. And keep your micro for your dev/test/preprod environments!

Edit: I got those info from an Amazon guy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your load balancer is pinging a blank html file. I got that message because it was pinging my home page which had db loads. When I set it to ping a blank html file it ran smoothly

Comment: Isn't that like fixing a fire alarm by disconnecting its power?